# When calculating the length of a roll, what is the significance of the 4 in this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\pi (D^2 - d^2)}{4 \times T \times 12}$$

$D$ = outside diameter of roll of material

$d$ = outside diameter of core in roll

$T$ = thickness of material

This equation gives the length of material on the roll. We can not figure out why the $4$ is there, though. Everything else makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the surface of the roll in your formula. Surface of a round object $A =\pi r^2$ or $\frac{\pi d^2}{4}$ with $r$ the radius and $d$ the diameter.

That's where the 4 comes from

Comment: You should let us know if this is the answer you were looking for.